# How can I run multiple Django servers from one Pycharm Project?

Tags: python, django, pycharm

I want to be able to run three different Django servers from within 1 Pycharm project, however, when you go into:

settings -> languages & frameworks -> Django

it seems that you can only set 1 Django project root, 1 Django settings.py file, and 1 Django manage.py file for all the Django servers you have running.

Short of creating a new Pycharm project for each Django server, which I do not want to do, is there any way I can have a separate configuration for each of the three Django projects?

[image]

Comment: The question is: what is from your perspective a "server" and a "project". What functionality do you expect?

Comment: A couple of things you will need to keep in mind. In general, there is nothing stopping you from running multiple services at the same time. The problem is going to be with the configuration you are providing each instance you are trying to run. Just the port conflict alone will cause a problem when you try to start both of them. The first question is, what is the problem you are trying to solve with wanting to run multiple processes at the same time?

Comment: I intend to run them on different ports. I want to be able to change the run configuration for each server.

Answer (score 0):

I'm on Pycharm 2021.1.1

[image: Pycharm setting]

There's a list of Opened Projects(Not Apps. Seperate Projects in Seperate Folders with their Own settings.py)

You can select each Project and enable Django Support and assign root and setting path

after that you can create new configuration for each project

Note that if you have only 1 projects Open you might not see the project list